# Склеивание двух чисел в формате hex в python

Tags: python, hex

Всем привет!

Реализовал код который выводит два значения 0xffff и 0xf38c.

```
def main():
    while True:
        id_device = instrument.read_registers(0x0006, 2)
        id_device.reverse()
        for i in id_device:
            print(hex(i))
```

Не могу их "склеить", чтоб получилось вот так - 0xfffff38С  (потом преобразую в десятичное число). Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> (0xffff << 16) | 0xf38c
4294964108
>>> hex(_)
'0xfffff38c'
```

Если у вас на входе 4 байта, то можно напрямую их в `int` превратить (Питон 3):

```
>>> int.from_bytes(b'\xff\xff\xf3\x8c', 'big')
4294964108
```

или:

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.unpack('!I', b'\xff\xff\xf3\x8c')[0]
4294964108
```

Если вы хотите просто hex представление в виде строки получить (Питон 3):

```
>>> b'\xff\xff\xf3\x8c'.hex()
'fffff38c'
```

Answer (score 2):

Если в id_device числа двухбайтовые, то можно использовать следующий код:

```
def main(): 
  while True: 
    id_device =  instrument.read_registers(0x0006, 2)
    shift=0
    result=0
    for i in id_device:
      result += i << shift
      shift += 16
    print(hex(result))
```

Comment: Никита, спасибо за помощь. Но есть нюанс. если я на весы ложу груз какой-нибудь - мне выдает соотвествующее значение. А вот если нету на весах ничего, то выдает какието нереальные значения. Может я чтото не догоняю?

Comment: Ну тут я думаю стоит посмотреть документацию к оборудованию. Возможно для обозначения отсутствия веса используется специальное магическое число и нужно просто сделать проверку. Сложно судить о чем-то исходя из того, чтобы дали. Ведь мне не известно ни оборудование, ни модули которые вы используете. И еще. Те "нереальные" значения всегда разные или это одно и то же?